# ABRSM: Piano performance diploma

Tags: piano, abrsm

The information on the ABRSM website isn't entirely clear to me.

Is there a diploma for piano performance only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean a diploma with no viva voce, sight-reading, or written requirements.

The [ARSM](https://gb.abrsm.org/en/our-exams/diplomas/music-performance/arsm-associate-of-the-royal-schools-of-music/) is the only such diploma offered by the ABRSM. It is a fairly new entry-level diploma.